# Is it possible to take all backed up data without jailbreak from iCloud (public,shared,private) by any app/tool, provided with iCloud credentials?

Tags: ios, mobile, icloud, jailbreak, mdm

I am trying to build a mobile monitoring tool/app for iOS without Jailbreak. The only possible way to perfectly access all installed app's content is through [iCloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit).

Also I found [Apple's MDM](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204142) come a little close to this for BYOD devices but yet accessing individual application's data is not possible.

During all this process, I came across some website [fonemonitor](https://my.fonemonitor.com/livedemo/dashboard.html) and [phonemonitor](https://www.phone-monitor.com/compatible-phones.html)  (with and without) who claim to do the same without Jail Break.

So here is my question is it possible to take any application's data if we get access to the users iCloud account? Also, are all public, private and shared data accessible via iCloudKit? As the documentation clearly states private data is untouched.

How does app monitoring work for any iOS Devices through these websites. Any lead would actually help!